# Logitech M510 mouse reciever fell in a glass of filtered water, is there a way to fix it?

Tags: windows-8, usb, mouse, water-damage

I've let it sit in rice for about two days now, and my computer does acknowledge that it's connected, but gives me the standard "USB device not recognized" spiel.  Troubleshooter does nothing, simply giving me the "Device Descriptor Request Failed" non-info.  I've tried reinstalling the USB driver and the USB hub before restarting.  I've tested on multiple computers and ports, with the same result every time.  I've made sure USB suspend is disabled.  Is there any possible solution, or do I just need to get a new mouse?

Comment: You might have got away with it if you'd immediately sprayed it liberally with contact cleaner, as it wasn't powered when it got wet & the water may have been low contaminant. Putting it rice & praying wasn't the right move, no matter what the interwebz might tell you. You didn't suffer initial shorting, but you've left it to corrode.

Comment: Damn.  Oh well, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's dead.

But in case of Logitech these dongles are replaceable. It's called a "Unifying receiver". You can use the Logitech mouse software to pair it to the mouse, or even multiple mice and keyboards.

By the way, you were lucky - plugging in a potentially water-damaged USB device like this could fry a USB controller on your motherboard in case of a bad short.

Comment: Would you suggest I buy a new receiver or just get a new mouse?  From googling, they'd be about the same price, sooo...

Comment: I'm seeing on Amazon, dongle £12, full set £27.

Comment: Huh, I'm seeing $$16.99 for a dongle OR the same model of mouse lol.  https://www.amazon.com/Logitech-Unifying-Receiver-Mouse-M905/dp/B00SYENY0M
https://www.amazon.com/Logitech-Wireless-Computer-Mouse-Side/dp/B003NR57BY